# How to develop a feature (that needs Facebook's user_friends permission) in an already active app?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I have an Android app that currently is integrated with FB but that doesn't use the user_friends permission. I want to implement a feature that uses this permission, but since the 1st of August FB needs to review the app (and the feature!) first to be able to grant you the ability to start asking for it. 
The problem is that, when I go to submit my app for review, FB asks me to include the reproduction steps to see the app use the permission, and also a video of it.

My question is: how can I submit my application for review if the feature hasn't been implemented yet? I can describe the feature but I can't post a video of it.

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I couldn't find any info regarding this.

Comment: Not sure if you still can ask people with a role in the app for this permission when not reviewed yet, while the app is in live mode. If not, then create a test app, and test & implement there. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

Comment: Have you got the solution for this? I am stuck on this from whole day. Still not getting any solution

Comment: I ended up using test accounts like the answer to the question suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Facebook test accounts to login and test. This Facebook test accounts already have all permissions granted by default and you can use to test your implementation without submit your application to get the permission.

Here are a explanation about where you can get this accounts in your dashboard in developer.facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users#managetool

Another option is to add real accounts from facebook with tester role in your dashboard accessing the options Roles -> Roles in the sidebar menu